# Adding widget on Live TV view

Tags: google-tv

Can we customize a Live TV View? Say for example,if i want to display a textview or a dialog box listing down current channelinfo, while Live TV is been played, can i add them dynamically on top of the Live TV view?
If anyone has tried adding widgets on Live TV View, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way of doing this at this time. We know that developers would like to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done for Google TV however, you can do this with Y! Connected TV. You may create a dialoge box over live TV on Yahoo! TV by envokeing a full-screen application and only taking up the defined space. The defined space may be as small as one pixel or as large as you would like. The Image may also be transparent to view live TV in the background.